# Finding a murderer from statements from suspects

Tags: logical-deduction

Officer X was entrusted with the duty of investigating a murder. The dead body was found in the living room.
Preliminary investigation suggested that four of the six suspects were liars (at least one of each of their
statements is a lie). Upon further interrogation, Officer X succeeded in extracting the following responses:

- A: “P and I were in the 2nd bedroom and M was in the bathroom.”
- O: “I agree with A. M was in the bathroom and P in the second bedroom, but
  A was in the living room.”
- P: “As far as I remember, O and J were in
  the kitchen and I was in the bathroom.”
- M: “P was in the second bedroom and C was in the bathroom. I saw A in the 1st bedroom.”
- C: “P
  and J were in the bathroom and O was in the kitchen.”
- J: “M was in the kitchen. P and I were in the second bedroom.”

From these replies Officer X immediately deduced who the murderer was.
Who was the murderer and what line of reasoning led him to his conclusion?

Answer (score 4):

> O is the murderer

Reasoning:

> We can see that for each person, if they are telling the truth, some others are lying. These are A:O,P,M,C,J; O:A,P,M,C,J; P:A,O,M,C,J, M:A,O,P,C; C:A,O,P,M,J; J:A,O,P,C. Since we know that there are only four liars, M and J have to be truthful. This means that P,C,A,M and J were not in the living room, leaving O as the only remaining suspect.